# Is it possible to use the GPT-2 model for time-series data prediction?

Tags: natural-language-processing, prediction, time-series, gpt

Is it possible and how trivial (or not) might it be (if possible) to retrain GPT-2 on time-series data instead of text?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely! but at that point it would be training a transformer-encoder (gpt2's architecture) and not GPT2 because GPT2 is defined by the weights / training procedure / data it was trained and not the architecture, and I don't think it would transfer properly to time series.

Comment: GPT-2 is a decoder, not an encoder.

Answer (score 0):

In TS tasks, Transformers can capture long-range dependencies effectively through their self-attention mechanism, which can potentially lead to better forecasting performance compared to LSTMs. However, they are computationally more expensive than LSTMs.

Comment: It's worth noting that their self-attention mechanism is quadratic in time and space with regard to the input length. This may be intractable for very long sequences (>> 1k). However, solutions to this problem have already been proposed, such as the [Sparse Transformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10509).